# Android TouchEvent in ListActivity..!

Tags: android, touchscreen, listactivity

I have created a list activity where i have placed some items and i am using 
OnListItemClick to get the desired actions through D-pad and KeyLeft and KeyRight Buttons, 
In Emulator TouchEvent is not working , I want to know whether it works in real Handsets???
How can i enable the TOuchEvent also, Can anyone please help me out in this.

Appreciate your Help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: if it's not working on the emulator, it won't work in a real handset.

Answer (score 0):

onListItemClicked should work for touch events, too. Perhaps the behavior is somewhat different for emulators because I wrote an app with a ListActivity and it registers touch events when I run it on my phone. Try this, when running in the emulator, hold down the mouse button a little longer before letting go. I've had problems before in the emulator where buttons don't trigger if you don't hold them down long enough.